# Spring Boot 2.2.1 suffix pattern issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have some tests that test PUTting a resource to an endpoint.  We support using path extensions to determine the content type of the request.  The tests that do not include the file suffix in the path pass fine; the test that does include the suffix fails with a 406.  The suffix is registered in ContentNegotationConfigurer and I've tried every combination of `spring.mvc.pathmatch.use-suffix-pattern`, `spring.mvc.pathmatch.use-registered-suffix-pattern`, `spring.mvc.contentnegotiation.favor-path-extension`, and `spring.mvc.contentnegotiation.favor-parameter` to no avail.

The request mapping in question accepts all values and produces html, xml, and json.

Debugging into the `DispatcherServlet`, I noticed in `RequestMappingInfo.getMatchingCondition`, the consumes condition properly matches, but the produces condition returns null.  Stepping in further, I see the ContentNegotiationManager has 4 strategies, one of them being `ServletPathExtensionContentNegotationStrategy`.  This class has a method `resolveMediaTypeKey`, which basically tries to look up the extension from registered media types.  Because my file extension and media type are registered, it matches and returns the media type for that extension (which is not html, xml or json) and in turn, the `ContentNegotationManager` returns that value to the `ProducesRequestCondition`.  At this point, the returned media type is compared to the declared `produces` values.  Since the value being returned does not match any of the declared produces values from the controller, the condition fails.

This seems problematic to me.  It seems like the behavior implies that if you PUT/POST/whatever a resource to a controller and it uses the file suffix to determine the content type of the request, it also attempts to force it as the return type when attempting to determine the handler mapping, which is not the case.

This was not an issue in Spring Boot 2.1.x.  Curious if this is a legitimate issue or if there is something I'm missing.